# Need to remove a specific folder from .htaccess mod-rewrite redirect rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using some software that sits in the /var/www/html folder and manages URL redirects through .htaccess (the software isn't Wordpress, but it manages URL redirects in a similar way).

I need to carve two folders (/var/www/html/folder1 and /var/www/html/folder2) out from the redirect rules, which are at the very bottom of the .htaccess file. I read through a ton of documentation but can't seem to make the following work in .htaccess (which sits in /var/www/html):

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /

    #force HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #carve out these folders
    RewriteRule ^/folder1($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/folder2($|/) - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I go to the directories in question (eg. https://example.com/folder1), I get: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder1/ on this server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I'm new but do the two folders have any sort of index page? Otherwise you will get a 403 response because you have disabled indexes at the top of your file excerpt.